# What is the type of the exception "Exception: Prelude.read: no parse"

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm trying catch the exception that happens when the user writes something different from than expected.

I'm doing this:

```
main = do
    {catch (take_number) fix_error;}
    where
        take_number = do
        {
            take_number "Give me a number";
            n <- readLn;
        }
        fix_error e = if Exception e then do
            {
                putStrLn "Invalid number! Try again";               
                main;
            }
            else ioError e
```

I don't the exception type that I need catch in `Execption`

Comment: `if Exception e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of exception you get when doing `readLn` is [`IOError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:IOError) which is just an alias for [`IOException`.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:IOException)

Here is how you could handle the error, I've added a type to `readLn` to enforce it to be read as an `Int`.

```hs
import           Control.Exception

main :: IO ()
main = catch takeNumber handleError

takeNumber :: IO ()
takeNumber = do
  putStrLn "Give me a number:"
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  putStrLn ("Success, your number is: " ++ show n)

handleError :: IOError -> IO ()
handleError e = do
  putStrLn ("Invalid number! Try again. The error was: " ++ show e)
  main
```